# Call a member function in a case of a when statement?

Tags: kotlin

For example, `Char` has a member function `isLetter()`. Is there any way to call it in a case? The code below does not work.

```
var ch:Char = null;

when(ch)
{
    '*' -> print("You typed an asterisk.");
    isLetter() -> print("You typed a letter.");
    else ->  print("You typed something.");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The uses of the parameter to [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression) are quite restrictive: equality, order with `<` &c, inclusion with `in`, type checking with `is`, and that's about it.  So for anything more complex, it's usually easier not to specify a parameter.  In this case, the following isn't much less concise or clear:

```
when {
    ch == '*' -> print("You typed an asterisk.")
    ch.isLetter() -> print("You typed a letter.")
    else ->  print("You typed something.")
}
```

Some points worth noting:

- Semicolons are not needed in Kotlin (except for a few rare ambiguous cases such as putting multiple statements on a line — which is rarely a good idea).
- `print()` does not add a trailing newline, which can cause problems; `println()` is more common.
- `var ch: Char = null` won't compile, because the type `Char` is not nullable.  Either give a non-null default value, or make it nullable by specifying the type as `Char?`.  However, in the latter case, you won't be able to call `ch.isLetter()`, because that would risk a NullPointerException.  So you'd either need to add a null case before that, or handle the null in that check, either with `ch != null && ch.isLetter()`, or `ch?.isLetter() == true` — both of which are ugly.

Answer (score 1):

There is, but there's also the possibility of it not being applicable in your situation.

`when` can be used without an argument, like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val ch: Char = 'd'
    
    when {
        ch.isLetter() -> println("It's a letter")
        ch.isDigit() -> println("It's a number")
        else -> println("It's neither a letter, nor a number")
    }
}
```

But if you make `ch` nullable like `var ch: Char? = null`, you won't be able to call member functions in that `when` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether `ch` is in a specific [CharCategory](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-char-category/). For `isLetter()` those are the following five:

```
when(ch)
{
    '*' -> print("You typed an asterisk.")
    in CharCategory.UPPERCASE_LETTER,
    in CharCategory.LOWERCASE_LETTER,
    in CharCategory.TITLECASE_LETTER,
    in CharCategory.MODIFIER_LETTER,
    in CharCategory.OTHER_LETTER -> print("You typed a letter.")
    else ->  print("You typed something.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first in your code `var ch:Char = null`
it must be `Char?`

the solution is simple don't put argument:

```
var ch:Char = 'c'

    when  {
        ch == '*' -> println("*")

        ch.isLetter() -> println("letter")

        ch.isDigit() -> println("digit")
            
        }
```

hope my answer helped you